# How to tilt the datetime string displayed on the pyqtgraph X axis

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I've solved the problem of pyqtgraph displaying datetime string on the X-axis, but many datetime string will cause overlap.
How to tilt the datetime string displayed on the pyqtgraph X axis to avoid overlapping across the display,I am deeply indebted to you for this help

```
self.topFiller = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.topFiller.setMinimumSize(2000, 9000)
graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.topFiller)
y1=[100,2,8,5,9,6,1,3,9,11,13,1,1,2,8,5,9,6,1,3,9,11,13,1]
x1=["2019-7-1\r\n11:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n12:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n13:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n14:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n15:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n16:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n11:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n12:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n13:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n14:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n15:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n16:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n11:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n12:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n13:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n14:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n15:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n16:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n11:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n12:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n13:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n14:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n15:11:11","2019-7-1\r\n16:11:11"]
xdict1=dict(enumerate(x1))
stringaxis1 = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
stringaxis1.setTicks([xdict1.items()])
pw = pg.PlotWidget(graphicsView, left="rate", bottom="time", title="g1/"+str(i)+" in rate",axisItems={'bottom': stringaxis1})
curvein=pw.plot(x=list(xdict1.keys()),y=y1)
pw.getAxis("bottom").setLabel( color='#0000ff')
pw.setXRange(0,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own subclass of AxisItem and reimplement its painting method. I just copied it from the source and modified the part that refers to the painting of the ticks. The trick is to "save" the state of the painter and rotate it before drawing the text, then "restore" it. Since rotation is based on the source position of the painter, I also had to translate to the textRect position and swap its width and height.

It might need some small polishing to ensure that the text is correctly aligned, but it should work, and it also sets the minimum height of the axis item based on the tick text.

```
class MyAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def drawPicture(self, p, axisSpec, tickSpecs, textSpecs):
        p.setRenderHint(p.Antialiasing, False)
        p.setRenderHint(p.TextAntialiasing, True)

        ## draw long line along axis
        pen, p1, p2 = axisSpec
        p.setPen(pen)
        p.drawLine(p1, p2)
        p.translate(0.5,0)  ## resolves some damn pixel ambiguity

        ## draw ticks
        for pen, p1, p2 in tickSpecs:
            p.setPen(pen)
            p.drawLine(p1, p2)

        ## Draw all text
        if self.tickFont is not None:
            p.setFont(self.tickFont)
        p.setPen(self.pen())
        for rect, flags, text in textSpecs:
            # this is the important part
            p.save()
            p.translate(rect.x(), rect.y())
            p.rotate(-90)
            p.drawText(-rect.width(), rect.height(), rect.width(), rect.height(), flags, text)
            # restoring the painter is *required*!!!
            p.restore()

stringaxis1 = MyAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
stringaxis1.setTicks([xdict1.items()])

# find the maximum width required by the tick texts and add a small margin
fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(stringaxis1.font())
minHeight = max(fm.boundingRect(QtCore.QRect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, t).width() for t in xdict1.values())
stringaxis1.setHeight(minHeight + fm.width('  '))
```